# Bad JSON to Custom JSON

Tags: python, json, jq

I am currently trying to massage undesirable JSON output that I am returning into a format that is more valuable to me. Answers should be using jq or Python code (I am using the pyjq library in python)

Here is the current JSON output:

```
[
 {"colour":"Red", "car": [ {"year":2000, "make":"Honda", "model":"Accord"} ] },
 {"colour":"Blue", "car": [ {"year":2015, "make":"Toyota", "model":"Camry"} ] },
 {"colour":"Red", "car": [ {"year":1999, "make":"Dodge", "model":"Ram"} ] }
]
```

Using jq or possibly looping through using Python, I would like to format this into a new JSON object that looks like this:

```
[
 { "Red":[2000,1999] },
 { "Blue": 2015 }
]
```

Does anybody know how I can format any JSON that looks like the first snippet above, and turn it into the desired outcome listed in the second snippet.

Comment: Does the "car" array always have exactly one object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jq** is perfect for this. Let's see what it can do. First, let's group the cars by color. `group_by()` takes an array and groups the elements by whatever sub-expression you want.

```
$ jq 'group_by(.colour)' input.json
[
    [
        {"car":[{"model":"Camry","make":"Toyota","year":2015}],"colour":"Blue"}
    ],
    [
        {"car":[{"model":"Accord","make":"Honda","year":2000}],"colour":"Red"},
        {"car":[{"model":"Ram",   "make":"Dodge","year":1999}],"colour":"Red"}
    ]
]
```

Then let's map each sub-array to a `{color: [years]}` object. The `map()` function takes an array and changes each input element into some new output element. We can use it to create the exact `{color: [years]}` objects we desire.

Let's start with a partial mapping. We'll pull out the colors and see what that looks like.

```
$ jq -c 'group_by(.colour) | map({(.[0].colour): []})' input.json
[{"Blue":[]},{"Red":[]}]
```

Perfect. We have the colors. Now to get the list of years we use `map` again, turn the sub-arrays of cars into arrays of years.

```
$ jq -c 'group_by(.colour) | map({(.[0].colour): map(.car[].year)})' input.json
[{"Blue":[2015]},{"Red":[2000,1999]}]
```

Answer (score 6):

If you loop through the data you can reform a new dict like:

#### Code:

```
output = {}
for datum in data:
    for car in datum['car']:
        output.setdefault(datum['colour'], []).append(car['year'])
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = [
    {"colour": "Red",
     "car": [{"year": 2000, "make": "Honda", "model": "Accord"}]},
    {"colour": "Blue",
     "car": [{"year": 2015, "make": "Toyota", "model": "Camry"}]},
    {"colour": "Red",
     "car": [{"year": 1999, "make": "Dodge", "model": "Ram"}]}
]

output = {}
for datum in data:
    for car in datum['car']:
        output.setdefault(datum['colour'], []).append(car['year'])
print(output)
```

#### Results:

```
{'Red': [2000, 1999], 'Blue': [2015]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`group_by` involves a sort, and is thus unnecessarily inefficient for the problem at hand. Here is a direct approach using jq.  It is similar to the python solution provided elsewhere on this page:

```
 reduce .[] as $car ({};
   .[ $car.colour ] += ($car.car | map(.year)) )
 | map_values(if length==1 then .[0] else . end)
 | [ to_entries[] | {(.key): .value} ]
```

The line beginning with `map_values` serves to meet the requirement that singleton arrays be avoided. The last line could be omitted if a dictionary of results is acceptable.

Notice that the above program will work even if the `.car` array has more than one element.